# How do I display the contents of a std::vector of my own datatype and display the name on the console using std::copy?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to display the contents of the `std::vector<User>` using `std::copy` in a similar way to how I've achieved it through `std::for_each` in the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
class User {
private:
    std::string m_sName;
public:
    User(std::string sName):m_sName(sName) {}
    std::string GetName()const {
        return m_sName;
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<User> vectNames;
    vectNames.emplace_back("Jack");
    vectNames.emplace_back("George");
    vectNames.emplace_back("Jose");
//How can I get std::copy to do what the std::for_each is doing?
    std::copy(vectNames.begin(), vectNames.end(), std::ostream_iterator<User>(std::cout, "\n"));
//The following line is what I really would like std::copy to do. 
    std::for_each(vectNames.begin(), vectNames.end(), [](const User &user) {std::cout << user.GetName() << "\n"; });
    
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more why you need `std::copy`? `std::for_each` seems indeed a better tool to do what you do. You are not really copying `vectNames` anywhere; in fact, you are [transforming](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) it, and the result of the transformation is what you want to print/"copy" to the screen.

Comment: I am a new programmer and am experimenting with different ideas.

Comment: Good to know. I've added an answer that you might like :)

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! I really appreciate you showing me a different approach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of your comment *I am a new programmer and am experimenting with different ideas*, I'm posting this answer as an alternative approach which also shows some algorithm that you might enthusiastic about.

I think that `std::copy` isn't the right tool if what you want to do is both

1. calling a member function on the objects in a collection, and only after that
2. copying/printing them to screen

One, and maybe the best, approach is the one in the [atru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64622798/5825294), which basically solves only point 2 with `std::copy` (and this is something you already knew how to do it, based on your question), and point 1 by overloading `<<`, which makes the trick.

The alternative I propose is based on the idea that "calling a member function on every object of a collection" is actually a *transform* operation of that collection. `std::transform`, however, just like `std::copy` acts on iterators, not on ranges, so they cannot be easily composed with one another.

Here comes Boost, with `boost::copy` and `boost::adaptors::transformed` which allow you to do this:

```cpp
boost::copy(
        vectNames | transformed([](auto const& x){ return x.GetName(); }),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n")
    );
```

where `vectNames` is "piped into" `transformed`, which applies the lambda on every element of the collection, resulting in a new temporary collection, which is the argument to `boost::copy`. If you were to use `std::copy`, you would have to store the temporary somewhere, e.g. in `temp`, before passing to `std::copy` its iterators `temp.begin()` and `temp.end()`.

The full example is below. I hope it will give you some insight in different, more functional, approaches.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
class User {
private:
    std::string m_sName;
public:
    User(std::string sName):m_sName(sName) {}
    std::string GetName()const {
        return m_sName;
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<User> vectNames;
    vectNames.emplace_back("Jack");
    vectNames.emplace_back("George");
    vectNames.emplace_back("Jose");

    using boost::adaptors::transformed;
    boost::copy(
        vectNames | transformed([](auto const& x){ return x.GetName(); }),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n")
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I’ve marked this one as best answer! I find it really fascinating some of the other ways you’ve shown me! This has added to my knowledge!

Comment: My IDE (Visual Studio 2019) isn't recognising the following includes: #include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp> Any potential solution to this? I have it in C++ 17.

Comment: @GeorgeAustinBradley maybe installing Boost? I'm on Arch Linux and everything works out of the box with it. I guess you're on Windows, and it's always a pain with it. Probably there's already done existing question about how to install Boost libraries.

Comment: That isn't about Windows, boost always need be installed and it apparently was in your ArchLinux . @GeorgeAustinBradley, best find info for boost in relation to the particular MS's product to avoid surprises.

Comment: @zdim, yes, I probably mislead the reader with the _out of the box_ part; what I mean is that installing Boost on Arch did not take more than one command, namely `pacman -S boost`.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply overload the `ostream` operator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class User {
private:
    std::string m_sName;
public:
    User(std::string sName):m_sName(sName) {}
    std::string GetName()const {
        return m_sName;
    }
    void print(std::ostream& where) const
        { where << m_sName; }
};

/// Overloaded ostream operator
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const User& user)
{
    user.print(out);
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<User> vectNames;
    vectNames.emplace_back("Jack");
    vectNames.emplace_back("George");
    vectNames.emplace_back("Jose");
    
    std::copy(vectNames.begin(), vectNames.end(), std::ostream_iterator<User>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

In general I always have an overloaded `ostream` as part of classes that store and output information.

Answer (score 0):

With c++20 you do not need anymore an external library. You have `ranges` and `views` in the language.

The code becomes:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ranges>
class User {
 private:
  std::string m_sName;

 public:
  User(std::string sName) : m_sName(sName) {}
  std::string GetName() const { return m_sName; }
};
int main() {
  std::vector<User> vectNames;
  vectNames.emplace_back("Jack");
  vectNames.emplace_back("George");
  vectNames.emplace_back("Jose");

  std::ranges::copy(
      vectNames | std::views::transform([](auto const& x) { return x.GetName(); }),
      std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n")
  );
}
```